# Система событий для методов класса

Tags: php, ооп

Задача в следующем:

нужно реализовать систему событий для класса таким образом:

```
class A {
   public function _a($index, $params) {
        onbefore_a($index, $params); // тут передаются параметры по ссылке 
        ...
        onafter_a($index, $params); // тут передаются параметры по ссылке 
        return [$index, $params];

   }
}
```

это пример, как я представляю. Суть в том, чтобы мог для каждого методо класса добавлять разные событие. И в любом месте на это событие повесить обработчик, который изменялся входные параметры или результат возвращаемй методом.  Или можно было бы через событие принудительно завершить выполнение метода и вернуть результат. Т.е. например в onbefore_a в зависимости от параметров смог бы сделать return [];

Или может другие хорошие методы есть? например через геттеры сеттеры?

Или подскажите как гуглить? т.к. гуглил обработчики событие и т.д. - ничего не нашел..

Может какие-то паттерны есть?

Answer (score 1):

Можно вызывать все методы через `__call`, где будут дополнительно дергаться обработчики. допуская, что сигнатуры методы и событий одинаковы.

Примерный код:

```
class Test {

    private $_events = [];

    private function a($index, $params){
        echo __METHOD__."\n";
    }


    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if(method_exists($this, $name)){


            if(is_callable($this->_events['onBefore_'.$name])){
                $this->_events["onBefore_$name"](...$arguments);
            }

            $this->$name(...$arguments);

            if(is_callable($this->_events['onAfter_'.$name])){
                $this->_events["onAfter_$name"](...$arguments);
            }
        }
    }

    public function addEvent($name, $handler){
        $this->_events[$name] = $handler;
    }

}
```

и использование

```
$t = new Test();
$t->addEvent('onBefore_a', function(&$index, &$params){
    echo "before handler\n";
    $index++;
    $params[] = 'onBefore';
});


$t->addEvent('onAfter_a', function(&$index, &$params){
    echo "after\n";
    print_r([$index, $params]);
});

$t->a(1, ['some', 'params']);
```

на выходе будет

```
before     -- вызов события before, изменение значений параметров
Test::a    -- вызов самого метода
after      -- событие после, печать измененных параметров
Array    (
    [0] => 2
    [1] => Array        (
        [0] => some
        [1] => params
        [2] => onBefore
    )
)
```